# What Javascript function Would Open an HTML File and Specify its iFrame Source

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have hundreds of html files which are Lessons in training courses and they are viewed normally as part of a Course. I now have been asked to allow the Users to be able to view the Lessons on their own and as such I want to open them within a single, common, lessonWrapper.html file which displays the individual Lesson content html files, let's call them lesson.html, within an iFrame in lessonWrapper.html. This way I can centre the content and add any navigational elements above or beneath the iFrame and not touch lesson.html at all which is important.

Just to be clear, the User browses the list of Lessons within a Flex (swf) file hosted within an html page, let's call it browse.html. The User clicks on a button and the following ActionScript is called:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {

// Call the 'loadLesson' Javascript function.
ExternalInterface.call("loadLesson", "004.html");
}
```

This calls the JavaScript function 'loadLesson', which is in browse.html, and passes the parameter '004.html' which is the name of the lesson we want to display within the iFrame of  lessonWrapper.html.

My JavaScript function in browse.html is like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadLesson(_path) {

    //alert("loadLesson called successfully.");

    var myWindow = window.open ("tdc/Lobjs/dev/lessonWrapper.html","window");
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

    alert("iFrame name: " + iframe.name);

    myWindow.frames[0].src = "JavaScript:'004.html'";

    myWindow.frames['lessonIframe'].onload = function() {
    alert('Window loaded')


    }
    //alert("iFrame.name: " + myWindow.frames[0].name);
    //document.getElementById('lessonIframe').src = _path;
    }

    </script>
```

As you can see I have been trying all sorts here and commented out some lines I tried earlier. I want to simply open lessonWrapper.html and display my lesson 004.html, which I passed as a parameter '_path', within the iFrame named 'lessonIframe'.

Perhaps I am going about this in completely the wrong way. I welcome your thoughts and sage advice.

Regards

Chris

Comment: you have to wait for the window to have finished parsing the document before you have access to any elements in its DOM.

Comment: That seems reasonable. Could I set up a callback or listen for an event when lessonWrapper.html has finished loading?